# std map and multimap iterators are the same?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, multimap

```
std::multimap<int, int> my_map;
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    my_map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(i, i));
    my_map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(i, i));
}

std::multimap<int, int>::iterator it(my_map.begin());
std::multimap<int, int>::iterator end(my_map.end());
for(; it!=end; ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}

std::map<int, int>::iterator it(my_map.begin());
std::map<int, int>::iterator end(my_map.end());
for(; it!=end; ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
```

Why do the two loops iterating over `my_map` yield the same results? Is there not a difference between std::multimap::iterator and std::map::iterator?

Comment: Your code has a bug (mismatch between iterator type and container type). Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. It's very, very difficult to understand the behavior of buggy code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The code compiles and runs fine. I am wondering why it does.

Comment: It has a bug. It's not going to behave as you expect. That's the nature of bugs. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. This is why programmers do their best to *avoid* bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible that the implementation of `std::multimap` and `std::map` on your compiler use the same iterator, or something that's accidentally compatible. That does *not* mean that this behavior is guaranteed. It could change in the next version of the compiler, not to mention using another compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The iterators are not the same, but the ordering is the same I think. For `multimap` or `map` the element are ordered by its keys. The order is determined by a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare).

In your example, the orders of the keys are same for both cases. I guess that's why.